# Diamond issue when trying to resolve it using virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

I am new in C++ and I am suck when resolving the diamond problem:
here the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Base class
class Base 
{
   public:
      virtual void getArea()
      { 
         cout << "Called by Base\n"; 
      }
};

// Derived class
class Rectangle: public virtual Base
{
   public:
      void getArea()
      { 
         cout << "Called by Rectangle\n";
      }
};

// Derived class
class Square: public virtual Base
{
   public:
      void getArea()
      { 
         cout << "Called by Square\n";
      }
};

// Derived class
class Triangle: public Rectangle, Square
{
   public:
      void blabla(){}
};

int main(void)
{
    Triangle Tri;
    Tri.getArea();

    return 0;
}
```

I got the g++ errors:

```
main.cpp:36:7: error: no unique final overrider for ‘virtual void Base::getArea()’ in ‘Triangle’
 class Triangle: public Rectangle, Square
       ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:45:6: error: request for member ‘getArea’ is ambiguous
  Tri.getArea();
      ^
main.cpp:29:12: note: candidates are: virtual void Square::getArea()
       void getArea()
            ^
main.cpp:19:12: note:                 virtual void Rectangle::getArea()
       void getArea()
```

I found on Internet that virtual inheritance resolves the problem So what is my mistake(s).

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think as a compiler: what method should you call ?

You have a triangle that is both a Square and a Rectangle and you are asking is area. Should your triangle choose to use `Rectangle.getArea()` or `Square.getArea()` ?

The compiler cannot know. A solution here is to overide the getArea() method, for instance:

```
class Triangle: public Rectangle, Square
{
   public:
      void blabla(){}
      void getArea()
      { 
         Square::getArea; //I'm a square
         Rectange::getArea; //I'm a rectangle
      }
};
```

This problem would be trigger even is there was no class Base. An exemple on use of diamond inheritance would look like this:

```
class Base
{
   protected:
      int x;
};


class Derived1: virtual public Base
{
   //some stuff
};


class Derived2: virtual public Base
{
   //some stuff
};


class Join: public Derived1, public Derived2
{
   int getX(){
     return x;
   }
};
```

In here, using virtual inheritance allows us to only have one instance of the Base class in the Join instance, instead of 2 without and an error on which x should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have two different classes at the same level of inheritance providing different overrides of a virtual method. The compiler cannot know which one should take precedence, so you need to provide your own override and do whatever you want (call either of the functions, both, or roll your own implementation).